# Loading a ctools modal on the home page

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have a front page that consists mostly of context rules to load various blocks, and for some users, a requirement to render a Ctools modal with a call to action. We aren't displaying much on the homepage besides a few views, and static blocks. I'm using [this guide](http://drupion.com/blog/10-steps-creating-ctools-modal-window-drupal-7) to build out the actual modal (which itself, will display a view with Contextual rules based on the user's settings) to show content tailored to them. Is there any in-code hooks I can use to activate this modal only on the home page, or should I look into the option of using a custom developed block (using `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view()`) to activate the modal on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ctools modal framework instead of those [insert-fancy-word-here]box JS library. Kudos.

Ctools module uses `js/modal.js` inside ctools module folder to attach Drupal Ajax events to links with `ctools-use-modal` class. That is all.

I can think about a few approaches.

### 1. Do not make them modal-enabled in first place.

If you are calling the `ctools_modal_text_button()` or the function that adds modal-compatible markup, you can wrap it with an `if` statement.

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  print ctools_modal_text_button(t('Open the modal'), 'my/path/nojs', '');
}
else {
  print l(t('Open the modal'), 'my/path/nojs');
}
?>
```

If you are using a block, cache modes `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE` and `DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL` won't be compatible with this. `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE` would work, but I doubt caching this block would improve performance. It can rather have a negative effect. `DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` would be best.

If you are hardcoding block contents, you can create two blocks, with different visibility settings based on the path.

### 2. Change the JS or CSS.

If you can't change the PHP, you still can change the JS and/or CSS. 
A CSS solution would be the easiest. Print both modal and non-modal links, and if the `body` tag has `not-front` class, you can hide the modal links.

```
.not-front .ctools-use-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

You can un-ajax links as well. 
Here is a sample code:

```
(function($){ 

    Drupal.behaviors.zzzzzz = {
        attach: function (context) {
           $('.not-front area.ctools-use-modal, .not-front a.ctools-use-modal', context).once('ctools-use-modal', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.click(Drupal.CTools.Modal.clickAjaxLink);
        // Create a drupal ajax object
        var element_settings = {};
        if ($this.attr('href')) {
          var base = $this.attr('href');
          Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax(base, this, element_settings);
          delete Drupal.ajax[base]
        }
      }); 
    }}
})(jQuery);
```

There are other questions about Drupal behaviors and using jQuery with Drupal 7. Basically, above code finds modal links from non-front pages, and removes the Ajax properties defined in `Drupal.ajax`, so clicking the item does not trigger the modal.